# Identify Html tags on Xml parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am doing an xml parsing and the response i am getting is a html code ..is it possible to load that response in a uiwebview..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following methods are probably going to be what you're looking for:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:NSString 
                baseURL:NSURL];
```

```
[webView loadData:NSData
         MIMEType:NSString 
 textEncodingName:NSString
          baseURL:NSURL];
```

You can pass an `NSString` or `NSData` object to the appropriate method and have it loaded into your webView easily.

Good luck,

Aurum Aquila

P.S. Those method signatures are hyperlinked.